# AngularJS routing in html5mode error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular-ui-router, url-routing

Here is my front-end AngularJS routing:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
$stateProvider
.state('main', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: '/views/main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
})

.state('review', {
    url: '/review',
    templateUrl: '/views/review.html',
    controller: 'NewReviewCtrl'
})

.state('model', {
    url: '/:make/:model',
    templateUrl: '/views/model.html',
    controller: 'ModelPageCtrl'
});
```

And here is my server-side routing (node.js):

```
//...some routes

app.use('/*', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(config.rootPath + '/public/index.html');
});
```

With `/review` route, everything works fine, but not with `/:make/:model`:

HTML:

```
<a href="" ui-sref="model({make: 'lenovo', model: 'thinkpad-t430'})">See more details...</a>
```

If I go to this page through that link, everything works fine, but if I refresh or go directly to `localhost:3030/lenovo/thinkpad-t430` I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

It is probably because of the `html5mode`. And I suggest it not working with this URL because, it is a 2 level URL.

**How can I fix this?**

Edit: Express.js config:

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
    next();
});
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(session({secret:"some_secret"}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(express.static(config.rootPath+"/public"));
```

Comment: please post your main html file and the module configuration. seems like problem with it.

Comment: It look like problem with module initialization, please provide your code related t module config

Comment: there isn't any other module config

Comment: Can you replicate the issue in a plunker? Here is a blank template you can fork: http://plnkr.co/edit/WprgipAdFBtxDKM6jogo?p=info

Comment: you have ng-app declared somewhere right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [created working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CPnB0My8P884e3QwpKuF?p=preview), which does use the same UI-Router setting as mentioned above. Everything is working. So, we should know now, that the Client side should be set properly.

The main and only difference is, more explicit setting, which allows us to omit `<base href="/" />` in the head

```
$locationProvider
  .html5Mode(
  {
    enabled: true, 
    requireBase: false,
  })
```

Or we can use the `<base>` element (check the index.html `<head>`) int that [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CPnB0My8P884e3QwpKuF?p=preview)

Seems like the issue is on the server side, please check twice:

#### [How to: Configure your server to work with html5Mode](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode)

Comment: That is really surprising. Could you please, try to check if `requireBase: true` and explicit `<base href="/" />` is working? if yes, then we should just play a bit with `<link>` elements.... I updated my answer and included `<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />` there...

Comment: I fixed it by putting `<base>` before the `<link>`' tags

Comment: Great job sir! enjoy amazing UI-Router ;)